# Twitter Preview for Link is not working while publishing status with Twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

when I publish a tweet with instagram-photo-url inside it, it does not creating preview for that link, am I missing something? I'm pretty sure the URL is correct.

[the tweet published by using api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjSxr.png)

[the code how I publish it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jnCz.png)

Comment: Instagram links don't have Twitter preview images by default, unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: @AndyPiper Hi Andy, I'm pretty sure it is, because If I try to paste a link of instagram post on tweet area on web/app, it generates the tweet card.